# Select from object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, object, select

I have a dataframe with an object in the column1. This object contains multiple values per row. I need to iterate over all values in the object, however I can only select the whole row. How can I select the values within the object row?

Dataframe:

```
d = {'column1': [{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Code so far:

```
df.column1.iloc[0]
```

This selects {1,2,3}, however I would like to select only the first element 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is necessary convert values to lists and then indexing:

```
d = {'column1': [{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df.column1.apply(lambda x: list(x)[0]))
0    1
1    4
Name: column1, dtype: int64
```

Or use `next` with `iter`:

```
print (df.column1.apply(lambda x: next(iter(x))))
```

Advantage is working also with empty `set`s - is possible set default value:

```
d = {'column1': [{1,2,3},{4,5,6}, {}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print (df.column1.apply(lambda x: next(iter(x), 'no match')))
0           1
1           4
2    no match
Name: column1, dtype: object
```